# Issue with Polars rolling_* functions with over

Tags: python, python-polars

I am doing a `rolling_sum` with `over`. I expect that the `rolling_sum` will behave the same as `sum`, but with a time-window.

- `sum` gives expected results when combined with `over(["X"])` and `over(["X", "Y"])`
- `rolling_sum` gives the same results for `over(["X"])` and `over(["X", "Y"])`, which is not what I would expect

See the code below to reproduce.

First create the dataframe:

```
xs = [f"X{i}" for i in range(2)]
ys = [f"Y{i}" for i in range(2)]
dates = [f"2023-09-{i+1:02d}" for i in range(10)]
all_combinations = list(product(xs, ys, dates))

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "X": [x[0] for x in all_combinations],
        "Y": [x[1] for x in all_combinations],
        "date": [x[2] for x in all_combinations],
        "qty": np.random.randint(0, 11, size=len(all_combinations)).tolist(),
    }
)

df = df.with_columns(pl.col("date").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, "%Y-%m-%d")).sort(
    ["X", "Y", "date"]
)
```

Next we create columns with `sum` and `rolling_sum` aggregations, done over "X" and then ["X", "Y"]
sum gives expected results, rolling_sum does not.

```
df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("qty")
        .sum()
        .over(["X"])
        .alias("sum_over_X"),
        pl.col("qty")
        .sum()
        .over(["X","Y"])
        .alias("sum_over_X_Y"),
        pl.col("qty")
        .rolling_sum("3d", by="date", closed="left")
        .over(["X"])
        .alias("3d_sum_over_X"),
        pl.col("qty")
        .rolling_sum("3d", by="date", closed="left")
        .over(["X","Y"])
        .alias("3d_sum_over_X_Y"),
    ]
)
```

I'd like to understand if I'm missing something in my expectation?

Answer (score 0):

You should sort by the column you're doing the `rolling_*` on prior to the operation, or the results won't make sense. I was able to get the two given columns to differ with

```py
df.sort('date').with_columns(
...
)
```

Comment: Yes, this does give different answers, but the calcs are incorrect. Upon more digging it seems that the problem is that there are repeated dates -- and Polars seems not able to handle it correctly.

Comment: If that's so, create an issue on Github I say!

Comment: Thanks, I think there is an issue filed over the last day! https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/11150